# Select table rows which have corresponding rows in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two tables students and courses and there is has_many relation between students and courses. I want to select those students which have corresponding rows in courses.

How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more clear

Comment: @Deepak it is clear, he wants to see a list of students who has at least some courses associated :)

Comment: This is a shockingly basic question that can be answered even with a half-arsed pass through the documentation. Read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

Comment: I would have liked to see how you declared the association in your models more explicitly. In general this is a good guide to follow when asking a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @H_Z, make sure to pick an answer that solves your problem and accept it (if there is such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select students that have associated courses you'd go with:

```
Student.joins(:courses)
```

Than, you can query/filter the above further by specifying columns to be filtered in courses table:

```
Student.joins(:courses).where(courses: { name: 'History' })
```

Comment: What is downvote for? How is this valid answer looks incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find students in a specific course:

You can add `has_many students` in the Course model which will give you access to:

`Course.find(1).students`

or

`Course.find_by_name('biology').students`

etc...

To directly answer your question, you would go with Andrey Deineko's answer, it will give you all of the Students who have Courses...